# Umbraco 7.2.0 - getting descendants of node using where clause in razor

Tags: razor, umbraco, umbraco7

Let's say I have a document type with alias `BlogPost`, which has properties:

- blogTitle (Text String)
- blogDate (DateTimePicker)
- blogBody (Rich Text Editor)

When getting the latest 5 blogs contained in the site, I would use the following snippet:

```
var blogList = CurrentPage.AncestorOrSelf(1).Descendants("BlogPost").OrderBy("blogDate desc").Take(5);
```

However, I am trying to retrieve the latest 5 blogs where the date lies in a specific range (for example: after 15 December 2014).

I know that you can use the `Where` clause with a condition contained in a `String`, but I am attempting to compare two DateTimes:

```
Convert.ToDateTime("blogDate") >= new DateTime(2014, 12, 15)
```

Is this possible to do with a `Where` clause?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The snippet to do this is as follows:

```
var blogList = CurrentPage.AncestorOrSelf(1).Descendants("BlogPost").
               .Where("blogDate >= @0", new DateTime(2014, 12, 15))
               OrderBy("blogDate desc")
               .Take(5)
```

This snippet was taken from a reply on the following [Umbraco forum topic](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-7/using-umbraco-7/60233-Getting-descendants-of-node-using-where-clause-in-razor?p=0#comment204103).